# RESTful web services - best way to return result of an operation?

Tags: rest

I am designing a RESTful API and I would like to know what the most RESTful way is to return details about an operation.

E.g. an operation on a resource occurs when some data is POSTed to a URL. HTTP status codes will indicate either success or failure for the operation. But apart from success/failure I need to indicate some other info to the client, such as an ID number.

So my question is, should the ID number be returned in an XML document in the response content, or should it be returned in some custom HTTP header fields? Which is more in line with the principles of REST? Or am I free to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an entity is a perfectly valid response to an HTTP POST.

You also do not need to return XML you could just use the content type text/plain and simply return a string value.

Using a header would require you to define a new custom header which is not ideal.  I would expect clients would have an easier time parsing a response body than extracting the information from a header.

Answer (score 0):

XML document makes the most sense.

Comment: It's what I've seen most often.  Headers are less obvious.

Comment: But is this RESTful? POST does not request a resource in REST, it modifies one. Most examples I've seen return the location of the new/modified resource in the Http header's Location field. Client is then free to request it if they want to see what they just modified.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a just an ID number, it would save overhead to do it just as an HTTP header. Building a correct XML document just for a single number would add much more overhead to the request.

Comment: But what's the right thing to do? What will clients understand most easily?

Comment: I guess that depends on the client... personally I would prefer JSON over XML

Comment: I meant why a document response instead of headers...I think that's what the original poster is asking, too

Comment: Yes, I'm talking a document vs header field for the ID returned. Document encoding type is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Well a header uses less space, but a document would be more readable by a person.

Comment: How did you determine that a header uses less space?  If my header is x-Created-Id: 45  and my response body is <Id>45</Id> then the header is going to take more bytes.

Comment: Because that isn't well-formed xml, you are forgetting the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` that should be on top, which would definitely push it over the limit.

Comment: An xml document does not require the Xml declaration to be considered well formed. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd  Also, there is no need to use XML at all.  Using text/plain as the content type would allow the body to just simply be 45.

Comment: Yea, echoing just "45" in the document body would probably be the cleanest solution, I just figured the OP was looking for JSON/XML system. +1